# The given key was not present in the dictionary while triggering test cases in mtm

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests, microsoft-test-manager, xamlbuild

I am trying to run coded ui test cases using MTM. I use XAML builds to run test cases in agent machine
While triggering test cases from local machine everything is working fine.
But when I am running test cases from MTM in an agent machine I am getting the below error message

```
Assert.Fail failed. (Getting values for Environment and Culture failed from MTM: The given key was not present in the dictionary.)
```

Can anyone please help?

Note : I do have some other test cases in different solution (with different XAML build) and they work fine.

I am using Visual studio 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason for this error was wrong test configuration settings.

The configuration variable which I was using in my app config were not present in the MTM configuration setting because of which it was giving me the above error message "The given key was not present in the dictionary".

As soon as I added the correct variable in my MTM test configuration manager and then added those to my run configuration sttings the error got resolved.